# Is there any indication that latinum is useful in production?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

We know latinum cannot be replicated which gives it its value in the Star Trek universe.  But usually with metal based-currency there is a productive use (not historically, but presently and in the future).  For instance today silver is useful for cameras and medical equipment.  Does anyone know if latinum is actually useful in the production of anything?

Comment: I question your premise - silver is useful now, but precious metals like silver and gold were historically useful for nothing but adornment... they just looked pretty, and there wasn't a lot of it readily available.

Comment: The future finds uses for just about everything.  Today gold is useful for other purposes.  Considering Star Trek is based much farther in future than where we are currently, there should be, theoretically, even more uses for gold, silver and other rare metals.

Comment: but they were precious long before they were useful, hence I question your premise "usually with metal based currency there is a productive use"

Comment: My premise is not meant to deal with the historical nature of precious metals but the present and future implications of it.  I changed the text to be a little more specific.

Comment: Actually, historically gold and especially silver *were* useful in the sense of being made into useful objects. Also, gold was always valued for its ability to resist tarnish.

Comment: Yes gold was made into useful objects historically, but nothing that couldn't have been made out of some other metal.  Tarnishing is also generally superficial.  The point is gold derived it's value from being rare and pretty and therefore coveted.  Today it's value is factored in with it's rarity on top of things that gold is actually useful for such as superconductivity and other useful properties.  Today gold has genuine production value in electronics, medicine and industrial processes.

Comment: These days gold is incredibly useful for making fantastic-sounding audio cables.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Latinum#Latinum_items) lists the known uses of Latinum. Note that *all of them* are vanity items:

> Renewal scroll inscription pens
>   Hair brooch
>   Tooth sharpener
>   Bucket
>   Waste extraction fixtures
>    - According to Nog, the waste extraction fixtures in the Nagal Residence are plated with latinum.
>   Bajoran earring

Additionally the "Divine Treasury" is said to be made out of solid Latinum. While it's a fictitious locale, its existence as pure Latinum also suggests its use purely for vanity.

Latinum is likely only valuable as it can not be replicated. Also note that the Ferengi are not a utilitarian species; money has inherent value to them, practical goods are only worth what they can be sold for.

A useless but impossible to replicate material is arguably the perfect currency for the Ferengi; it's the one thing you couldn't sell for *more money*. Ferengi obsession over what is basically *pure money* is likely commentary; one that would be lessened if they had practical reasons for their greed.

Comment: Additionally, gold was used as a currency initially because of its rarity (and vanity items like jewelry). It wasn't until later that it was discovered to be a good electrical conductor.

Comment: Very true. Latinum seems to be an extreme analog of gold in terms of currency and vanity usages. Pressing it with gold and using it in little tiny gold bars seems to drive the point home...a bit heavy handedly, too.

Comment: You might want to remove The Divine Treasury from that list, as it's not real.  It's the afterlife in Ferengi mythology.

Comment: @Keen thanks. The description of the Divine Treasury also hints at Latinum's use as an object of vanity/greed so I included it as a separate note.

Comment: Wasn't latinum a liquid, which is why it was normally gold pressed